# Parent child hierarchy in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have the following requirement,

Input

```
CID ParentID

1   10
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   4
9   4
10  NULL
20  25
30  38
15  51
17  71
```

when I pass child value as 4 following is my desired output:

Desired Output:

```
CID ParentID
2   4
1   2
10  1
NULL    10
4   2
4   8
2   4
2   5
2   6
1   3
2   7
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Explain deeply

Comment: well I could write hardcoded procedure getting this input and giving this output is it ok for you? If not, please explain what do you want

Comment: what jus happened mate?

Comment: it was ok @roman pekar I would like to pass 4 as input

Comment: @ManojGade can you explain on what basis you want this output

Comment: @AmitSingh when I pass a child value I need to get details of all its parent and the details of child values of the those parents. please revert if i am not clear

Comment: do you really need record 2   4 twice?

Comment: I don't get it. For value 4 you get parents 2 -> 1 -> 10 -> NULL. How did you get record where CID = null and ParentID = 10?

Comment: -1 : I think column name in `Desired Output` should be `CID ChildID` insead of `CID parentID`.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation and your data don't match. I think the row (4, 2) in the results should be (4,9). If I'm correct, then this should do what you want:

```
with Parents(lvl, CID, ParentID) as (
  select 0, ParentID, CID
  from T
  where CID = 4
  union all
  select lvl+1, T.ParentID, T.CID
  from T join Parents
  on T.CID = Parents.CID
)
  select CID, ParentID
  from Parents
  union all
  select T.ParentID, T.CID
  from T join Parents
  on Parents.ParentID = T.ParentID;
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42c77/13).

Comment: can I recurse it to next->next level: say suppose if 8 is parent and it is having child values can i get them as well?